# Failing to display a class property value in view angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get user location from a service and display it in a component view.I could very well get the location from service into component.But when i display it in view it displays as undefined.
Below is the code.

**Service:**

```
enteredLocationName = new Subject<string>(); 

sendEnteredLocationName(location) {
    this.enteredLocationName.next(location);
}
getEnteredLocationName() {
    return this.enteredLocationName.asObservable();
}
```

**Component-TS:**

```
export class RestaurantSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  enteredLocationName: Subscription;
  enteredLocation:string;

  constructor(private shareDataService: ShareDataService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEnteredLocationName();
}

getEnteredLocationName(){     
 this.enteredLocationName = 
 this.shareDataService.getEnteredLocationName().subscribe(resp => { 
        this.enteredLocation = resp;               
    });        
 }
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.enteredLocationName.unsubscribe();
 }
}
```

**Component-View:**

```
input [value]="enteredLocation" type="text" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Selected Location"
```

Comment: Can you try using `ngModel` rather than `[value]` for the input property?

Comment: The problem is with the Subject. After I change Subject to BehaviorSubject, it worked fine. ngModel is also point to be noted.Thanks for your help..

Comment: Glad you found the solution! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using  Subject, it doesnt hold any values, its just invoke the subscription when ever you change its value. hence, its persistent value is undefined.

You should use BehaviorSubject instead, which can hold persistent value.

```
 enteredLocationName = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
```

Comment: As you say , the problem is with the Subject. After I change Subject to BehaviorSubject, it worked fine. ngModel is also point to be noted.Thanks for your help..

Comment: No problem, if my answer helped you, please mark it as answer. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Bind with `ngModel` instead of `value`.

As in the initial stage `value` binds the value which is undefined so after getting value it will not update the value but `ngModel` does.

Else you can try with `async` pipe. if you want to use value.

```
<input [value]="enteredLocation | async" type="text" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Selected Location">
```

PS: I am not sure with `async` will works or not.